# Visual Studio - typescript project out of sync

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

I've got community 2015 version of Visual Studio. I'm working on a project in typescript and I've got problem with syncing modified datas with browser. Typically i'm working on some part of code, debug it and change, then ctrl + save and ctrl + r to refresh browser. And It looks that newly generated source maps aren't applied becouse I still have old version of .ts code! (but javascript is corrected). So javascript and .ts arent synced eachother and it's really hard to debug. What should I do to make it work?

EDIT:

ofc, My files are edited in Visual Studio, not in browser.

ALSO:

I noticed that in most cases it's good to work on anonymous mode in chrome. It helps to keep files synced (even I've got checked disable cache).

Answer (score 0):

> It helps to keep files synced (even I've got checked disable cache)

For development you should return the file with cache disabled using http header:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Comment: I appreciate that you posted this answer 5 years ago, but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control), the combination of `no-store` and `must-revalidate` as you have shown in your example do not make sense because in order to go through revalidation you need the response to be stored in a cache, which `no-store` prevents.